# Not Downloading Files in HTML

Tags: html

I am trying to create a download link to a file I've created but it is not working. I've tried it without the `<img>` and without the download specification but nothing seems to work!

```
<a href="Downloadable File.txt" download="file">
    <img src="downloadbutton.png">
</a>
```

All it does is redirect me to a page without the file downloading like it's supposed to, how do I fix this?

Comment: Might be because you have a space in the file name, but not 100% sure

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it isnt

Comment: I believe it is just a browser behavior issue. Depending on the browser, some file types will automatically download, while others will by default just display in a new tab (e.g. images).

Answer (score 1):

Try this and make sure that your file exists on the server or at least at the right path.

```html
<a href="path/to/your/download/file" download="filename">
   <img src="downloadbutton.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Is it not just the `download` attribute?
i.e
`<a href="path/to/your/download/file" download>
   <img src="downloadbutton.png">
</a>`

Comment: it just gave me this in response https://prnt.sc/poiey0 (IDK if this helps but im using firefox)

Answer (score -1):

It is not `download="file"`.
It should be `download` only.

And please check your `href`. It should be some path to your file.

```
    <a href="path/to/your/file.txt" download>
        <img src="downloadbutton.png">
    </a>
```

Comment: Either way should work. `download` only specifies that the file is to be downloaded; `download="file"` specifies in addition that the new file name should be "file" .

Comment: Oh sorry, that's a mistake. Try to change the href to your file path. like "path/to/your/file.txt". @Slykaj72